# How does skype remain on top when call is in process and you switch to other app in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, skype

what iOS feature does skype app use where it can remain on top of other apps with a drop down like bar even if you run other apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skype uses the iOS 4 multitasking APIs, specifically VoIP multitasking in order to keep the call active while the rest of the app is suspended.

When the app is sent to the background, Skype informs the system that it would like to keep its network connection alive and that the audio subsystem should remain active.

The system continues to look after the network connection, passing received data back to Skype in order for it to process the audio.

This is one of the three main forms of multitasking in iOS, the others being: audio streaming, like Pandora and location services, like Tom Tom navigation.

Comment: but that only explains background presence how does it keep its UI on top of all other apps?

Comment: It doesn't - the red bar is shown by the OS when the audio system is in use by an applicaiton from the background.

Answer (score 1):

It does this via the background execution APIs available starting in iOS 4. More information about how it works can be found in the **Implementing a VoIP Application** subsection on [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) in the iOS Application Programming Guide.

Comment: but that only explains background presence how does it keep its UI on top of all other apps?

Comment: Apps that use the VoIP APIs get to have the bar at the top, as far as I know.